# If $A$ is a semisimple algebra, then every $A$-module short exact sequence splits

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra

I know that if $A$ is semisimple, then every $A$-module is semisimple. But I don't know how to prove then that a short exact sequence
$$0 \to L \to M \to N \to 0$$
splits for every $A$-modules $L,M,N$. Can someone help me please ? Thank you